# Как в pupeeter сделать waitFor который ничего не ждет?

Tags: node.js, тестирование

Как в pupeeter сделать waitFor который ничего не ждет? Мне надо добавить waitFor который всегда удолетворен.

Comment: передать 0?____

Answer (score 0):

[`page.waitFor()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) уже какое-то время deprecated. Не совсем понятно, зачем вам это. Но достаточно вроде [`page.waitForTimeout(1)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds) или [`page.waitForFunction('true')`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args).